# inequality involving taking expectation

Tags: calculus, probability

There are three convexly decreasing functions $\mathbb{R^+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}$. $f,g $ and $h$.
I'm wondering whether it's true that

$E[f(x)^2]E[g(x)h(x)]<E[f(x)g(x)](1+E[f(x)h(x)])$

for an arbitrary probability distribution.

Comment: @simeon, it seems to be true in your example. I'm not sure whether it's ture. Maybe I'm more curious in a possible condition on $f,g$ and $h$ for this inequality to hold. like they are bounded by certain value..

Comment: No. See counter-example below.  The idea is to try to perturb a situation where $E[f(X)^2]=\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, here is a counter-example. Let $X$ be uniform over $[0,1]$.  For $x \geq 0$ define:

\begin{align} 
&f(x) = \frac{1}{x+0.01} \\
&g(x) = h(x) = e^{-x}
\end{align}

Then: 
\begin{align} 
&E[f(X)^2] = \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{x+.01}\right)^2dx \approx 99.0099 \\
&E[f(X)g(X)] = E[f(X)h(X)] = \int_0^1 \frac{e^{-x}}{x+.01} dx \approx 3.8606 \\
&E[g(X)h(X)] = \int_0^1 e^{-2x}dx \approx 0.43233
\end{align}

So: 
$$ E[f(X)^2]E[g(X)h(X)] \approx 42.8 > 18.76 \approx E[f(X)g(X)](1+E[f(X)h(X)])$$

Comment: Thank you! I just post another question like this with the condition that f(x)h(x)<1. Your example is quite useful.

Comment: I see you have edited the question to add a condition $f(x)h(x)<1$, which was not there when I answered the question.  That is kind of annoying since it makes my answer look incomplete.

Comment: sorry about that I posted a new question with the condition added.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at the other one if I have time.

Comment: Okay I answered that question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184532/inequality-involving-taking-expectations